# Error with Address Book in Outlook 2007

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007

Have a bit of an issue concerning Exchange, was wondering if you could help me out

THE OAB doesn’t seem to be updating with users that use Outlook 2007, with 2010 is works fine it downloads the latest address book but with 2007 you get the following error

Task 'users email address' reported error (0x80004005) : The operation failed

Having a bit of a google around, I found that some people thought it was a DNS issue concerning the autodiscover, so I added into DNS autodiscover.mango.local – “address of active directory)

This changed the error message to the one we get above, so I made progress but it’s still not working.

Others have mentioned that it’s the authentication in the IIS server for autodsicover, they said change it to basic authentication but testing this this made no difference either.

Comment: Try deleting and redownloading the OAB on one of the affected clients.

Comment: I have done this, it happens with new users, if i rebuild the profile in outlook it has no effect.

Comment: I think this was due to the auto discover not working, found out in the end that our SSL certificate was incorrect and we did not have a auto-discover entry in our DNS. after hours of playing around and creating new certificates with the correct URLS and setting OAB and Virtual directories i have managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply for everyone but the problem i was getting was the auto-discover feature was not working.

This was due to the fact we recently changed our OWA external address due to a out source company not willing to sell us our domain back (not nice people)

When this happened the certificates in exchange were not updated, so when updating them i also set-up the auto discover settings, by adding a entry for it in DNS.

When the certificates were flushed through to all clients they were then able to download the address book.

The best information i found when to Hold CTRL and right the outlook icon in the system tray and select "Test E-Mail Auto Configuration" when this box loads up input the correct details and only have ticked auto discover and click test

You can then watch the log and see what address its trying to connect to, this is when i discovered that this had not been set-up in exchange and actived

Hope this helps